# In Angular2 routing, with new router, how do i redirect empty path only?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Environment: RC4 with new router

I have the following router config ..

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  {path: 'search-documents', component: SearchDocumentsComponent},
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    redirectTo: '/search-documents'
  },
  {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
];
```

It works as follows ...

http://SERVER ------------------> http://SERVER/search-documents

http://SERVER/ -----------------> http://SERVER/search-documents

http://SERVER/does-not-exist ---> http://SERVER/search-documents

BUT I want ...

http://SERVER ------------------> http://SERVER/search-documents

http://SERVER/ -----------------> http://SERVER/search-documents

http://SERVER/does-not-exist ---> NotFoundComponent

How do I achieve this please?

Additional Info:

If I remove ..

```
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'prefix',
    redirectTo: '/search-documents'
}
```

I get ..

http://SERVER ------------------> NotFoundComponent

http://SERVER/ -----------------> NotFoundComponent

http://SERVER/does-not-exist ---> NotFoundComponent

Comment: Why do you use `prefix` for `pathMatch` instead of `full`?

Comment: This change fixed it! many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `full` instead of `prefix`

```
pathMatch: 'full',
```

`prefix` tells the router to continue looking for matching routes while `full` makes it consume the full path and stop searching for matches.